# The use of built in php functions

Tags: php, function

My friend just give me a challenge, he wanted to test my programing skill. He ask me to build a function that do something.
So I went and built him the function he wanted. 
When he saw my function he was surprised that in my function I used a number of php built in functions.
He said that a good programmer just builds his own functions and the use of built in functions is considered sloppy code. So I told him that php is a scripting language and no mater what the built in functions are faster because they build in the source code in c++, and its difficult to build function like this in a scripting language.  What do you think, Is my friend correct in what he says?

Comment: You are right in general.

Comment: You might make a good programmer.... Your friend, maybe not so good as he thinks

Comment: Why would you re-invent the wheel. So you and your friend needs to build a fire.. you whip out your BIC© lighter.. while he mines sulfur and cuts trees down to make matches.. Um. yeah

Comment: This looks like a question for Software Engineering not StackOverflow

Comment: Show us your function.

Answer (score 3):

No, your friend is wrong. Not just for PHP, but for most any language out there.

As you correctly surmised, built in functions are almost always faster, and reinventing the wheel just introduces more potential problems and security vulnerabilities.